# Tracking just the feet with a kinect

Tags: c#, c++, kinect

Is there a way I can track just the feet with a Kinect?

I want to place a Kinect underneath a table, then isolate the feet and use them for my program. However I'm unable to get the feet without creating a full skeleton first

I am using the original Kinect with SDK v1.8

Comment: I'm assuming this is Kinect One with a windows adapter?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I'm using the original kinect with SDK 1.8. I've edited my post now.

Comment: The feet are low in the bone hierarchy, so I would think you would have to instantiate the whole skeleton. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973073.aspx

Comment: I wonder, is wearing two distinctive items, one on each leg, an option? This way, you might be able to utilise the object tracking capability without having to worry about the skeleton... I think

Comment: @Wolfish I was thinking of using OpenCV and some brightly coloured socks, but ideally I'd like to be using the depth data from the kinect to isolate the feet

Answer (score 0):

Using the depth and skeleton data alone, it is not possible to isolate just the feet, without having first obtained the full body frame (without hacking the Kinect). The best way to get just the feet is either by using Computer Visualization on the depth data or the colour data as you mentioned.

If you have some strong IR source that is around the 83 nm range and that can be affixed to the feet, you could potentially use the depth date and OpenCV to select the brightest area and map it as the feet. The bright coloured or different coloured socks method as you mentioned would also work.